# How to disable print key using terminal?

Tags: command-line, keyboard

In my application I have to disable print key during the application process and later need to enable it. I have tried with `xmodmap -e 'keycode 107 = '` but it doesn't resolve. The purpose of the disabling is user should not take the screen-shot while the application is running.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the <kbd>PrintScr</kbd> key only prevents clueless users from taking screenshots. It's almost trivial to change the session-wide short-cut key(s) to a different key combination via `gnome-control-center keyboard shortcuts` or its Unity/Xfce/KDE counterpart and on top of that one can also run a screenshot application like `gnome-screenshot`. In fact, any application connected to the same display server can request a copy of the frame buffer content.

If your application and its security model rely on not having screenshots taken of it, you need to seriously question its use case since that's just not going to happen. At the very least a user could simply take a photo of the screen.

Comment: I have removed executable permission from `gnome-screenshot` using command of `sudo chmod -x /usr/bin/gnome-screenshot` it's working fine but problem is asking password because we are using `root` privileges so how to execute same command without using  `root` privilege.

Comment: @Dinesh: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.